# Why does the compiler not infer the generic type

Tags: c#, generics, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer, type-inference

I have the following method:

```
public static void Foo<T>(Predicate<T> validator) { ... }
```

And I want to call it the following way:

```
Foo(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Why can't the compiler figure out `s` is `string` and therefore `T` is `string`? What rule in the spec makes the inference algorithm fail here?

Comment: Note that you can create a delegate from `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, you don't need the lambda (and in fact the lambda just creates an extra layer which slows things down a tiny bit)

Comment: @BenVoigt But wouldn't that oblige me to explicitly specify the generic type which obviously will make type inference work? `Foo<string>(string.IsNullOrEmpty)` or even `Foo(new Predicate<string>(string.IsNullOrEmpty))`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Yeah, was editing my comment when you wrote yours. I was just wondering the reason behind this. I still think the compiler should have gottten this right; there is no ambiguity about the call, only one candidate is valid, therefore the lamba parameter's type can be inferred. Maybe simply due to consistent behavior they chose not to have the compiler reason this out as it wouldn't be immediately obvious why sometimes inference would or wouldn't work.

Comment: Well yes, to exactly the same degree you are required to specify it now.  If anything, the method group is much more constrained than a lambda, since it can only match overloads with that exact name found in that exact class -- there's some inference work required for the compiler to reach the same information starting with the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I haven't checked the entire C# 5.0 specification, but section **8.5.1 Local variable declarations** talks a bit about the `var` keyword, which is used to declare an inferred type.

Here are the rules for variables declared for `var` and for all inferred variables:

- The local-variable-declaration cannot include multiple local-variable-declarators.
- The local-variable-declarator must include a local-variable-initializer.
- The local-variable-initializer must be an expression.
- The initializer *expression* must have a compile-time type.
- The initializer *expression* cannot refer to the declared variable itself

Because this is a lambda, your inferred initializer is:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
```

OK, so...

- It doesn't have multiple local-variable-declarators. Pass.
- It includes a *local-variable-intitalizer* because it's a lambda. Pass.
- It's an expression. Pass.
- string.IsNullOrEmpty returns a string. Pass.
- It relies on itself being passed to a function to determine the type.  Fail.

So, to answer your question, your initializer ultimately fails because its type must be known before you can pass it to a method.

Lambdas can fix this relatively easily, though:

```
Foo(string s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so basically the reason is that the lambda parameter type can not be inferred from the method's formal parameter type, because in order to resolve the method call you need to know the parameter type itself; you end up running in circles. That makes sense I guess although it *is* a bit startling that the algorithm should fail in such obvious cases but still manage to do a good job in much more convoluted scenarios. I knew the solution was easy; explicitly specifyng the lamda's parameter's type or the generic type itself; both are just one `string`. I was just wondering why.

Comment: I guess I'm nitpicking here, but this should have been a scenario where the compiler should have gotten it right; if the candidates set of valid methods contains only one candidate (as in this case), inference should work. `s` can only be `string`, there is no other valid overload that could make the compiler unable to decide on the better match.